# Completely reducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Is there an example of an $R$-module $V$ such that if $V_i$ is an infinite collection of submodules of $V$ such that $V/V_i$ is completely reducible, for each $i\in I$, then $V/\left(\bigcap_{i\in I} V_i\right)$ need not to be completely reducible?

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_i$ be the $i$th prime. Let $V=R=\mathbf{Z}$. Let $V_i=p_iR$.